# "Possible bug" I received the "Vote Down" privilege when my reputation is not enough for obtain it

Tags: soporte, estado-por-diseño, reputación, notificaciones, privilegios

After login on Spanish StackExchange site, I received the **"Vote Down"** privilege, but, my reputation is currently 116 and the [vote-down privilege page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) says:

> Awarded At: 125 Reputation

It is a *possible* bug?

Comment: Were you actually able to down vote something? The button will appear regardless, but when you click it, you will be told you don't have permission.

Comment: @Flimzy I'm not able to down vote, but as my question says "I received the “Vote Down” privilege when my reputation is not enough for obtain it". I already checked and the popup window appears when I try down vote (because I haven't the enough repuattion), I'm trying report this _behavior_ :)

Comment: That can happen if you were above 125 rep at one time, but then lost rep (due to down votes, or un-up votes or other such activity). But it doesn't appear that this happened to you. So I'm not sure what happened--it may well be a bug. At minimum, it probably requires investigation from one of the SE developers.

Comment: what do you see if you check the "privileges" tab on your main profile? Do you have a check next to vote down? Did you see that you were granted this privilege on the "recent activity" tab?

Comment: @Diego The only _notice_ that I have about this privilege is in the "achievements" section "right side of Stack Exchange logo, next to _inbox_ section".
BTW: I offer apologies if in future answers about my question will be in spanish :) "@Diego, you could also check my profile if I'm missing something (but I'm sure that this is the only reference to "Vote Down" privilege) that I have".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That day, 20 Nov 2014, [your reputation was on 116 points](http://stackexchange.com/users/5080114/mauricio?tab=reputation):

[image]

Checking your [reputation activity](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5764/mauricio-arias-olave?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=3) we observe:

[image]

That is, the message:

> There were no net reputation changes on this day

It shows following the logic described by Nick Craver (a Stack Exchange developer) in [New reputation is too verbose: upvote/unupvote, upvote again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125137/209901):

> We now rollup in a fairly simple way: if there are 2 of a reversible vote type, we hide that group if it's within the context of a day. We won't hide something accepted yesterday then unaccepted today for example.

And most probably it belongs to some upvote you received in [your only answer that day](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5764/mauricio-arias-olave?tab=answers) which was in [Voy vs. Vengo, both correct?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10285/1674).

Since your post has [an edition](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/10285/revisions), it is most likely that someone upvoted your post and then, later on, retracted the vote. Since you edited it, the vote became unlocked again and gave plenty of time to a user to retract it. That gave you some 126 reputation for a while and the system had time enough to grant your the [downvoting privilege](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) set at 125.

As indicated in [Why did I receive a message saying I have been granted a privilege, yet I don't have enough reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73673/209901):

> Your reputation was indeed over the threshold briefly (thereby triggering the message), but a voter changed their mind, reducing your reputation back below the threshold.
>
> Note that once you receive a privilege notification message, you will not receive a second message for the same privilege, regardless of how many times your rep goes over the threshold again.

So all of this seems to make sense and be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).